# Running a sql server stored procedure using CakePHP

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, stored-procedures

I'm wondering if this is the correct syntax on running microsoft sql server stored procedures using cakePHP. Is this the correct syntax when executing a stored procedure in CakePHP?

```
$this->Main->query("Exec uspGetVendorVehicleManifest '1/6/2014', 'wali.americantour', @pcolVehicleVendorIDInt = 1,@pRouteFrom = 0, @pRouteTo = 0");
```

The stored procedure has the following parameters:

```
    @pDate              AS DATE,
    @pUserID            AS VARCHAR(50),
    @pRegionIDInt       AS INT,
    @pPortIDInt         AS INT,
    @pcolVehicleVendorIDInt AS INT,

    @pStartRow          AS INT,
    @pMaxRow            AS INT,
    @pLoadType          AS INT,
    @pOrderby           AS VARCHAR(20),

    @pRouteFrom         AS TINYINT,
    @pRouteTo           AS TINYINT,
    @pCityFrom          AS VARCHAR(5),
    @pCityTo            AS VARCHAR(5),
    @pStatus            AS VARCHAR(4),
    @pRole              AS VARCHAR(50)
```

I'm only using some parameters as the other parameters are not essential.

Is this correct?

Comment: what does your log is telling you in tmp/logs folder

Comment: @justrohu I checked the logs and there seems to be no log about the problem with the stored procedure.

Comment: ok... did you check my answer is it working because at my side this syntax works only difference is I am using mysql

Comment: I'm still trying it.

Comment: which version of CakePHP was this?

Answer (score 3):

I've finally found a solution to this. You can use the exec command then add the value to the parameters that you will be using.

```
$this->ControllerName->query("exec storedProcedure @param1 = 1");
```

Though I have noticed that when I run it on cakephp, with php 5.5, the apache service would most likely crash. Probably because I am using an unofficial phppdo.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

I am assuming that your procedure name is uspGetVendorVehicleManifest

```
$query = "call uspGetVendorVehicleManifest('1/6/2014', 'wali.americantour', @pcolVehicleVendorIDInt = 1,@pRouteFrom = 0, @pRouteTo = 0)";

$result = $this->query($query);
```

I use procedure method with mysql since under the hood cakephp uses pdo I think this method should work.. let me know what happens as I also wanted to learn how it's done.

Comment: I'll try it with this, but if worse comes to worst. I might create a new stored procedure as well, It seems that cakephp has some problems with regards to very complex stored procedures